# Apache commons Email Alias Not working Properly in scala

Tags: scala, email, apache-commons-email

I am using HtmlEmail Class of ApacheCommons for sending HTML formatted email with embedded images

Apache Commons Email API (v1.4) is used in my Scala project

I am not Seeing the Alias (MY REPORTS) as sender name in my Received Email

Following is my Function

```
@throws(classOf[EmailException])
  @throws(classOf[Exception])
  def createHTMLEmailMessage(htmlContent: String): EmailMessage = {

    val email = new HtmlEmail

    // alternative message if the client does not support html

    email.setHtmlMsg(htmlContent)

    email.addTo("TO_address@gmail.com")

    email.setFrom("MY_address@GMAIL.com", "MY REPORTS")

    email.setHostName("MY_HOSTNAME")

    email.setSmtpPort(587)

    email.setAuthentication("USERNAME","PASSWORD")

    email.setStartTLSEnabled(true)

    email.setSSLOnConnect(false)

    email.setSubject("Subject")

    val emailMsg = EmailMessage(email)

    emailMsg

  }
```

Comment: UPDATE


When we do View Source on Email Received in Outlook, 
in Source 

From: MY REPORTS <MY_address@GMAIL.com>
To: <TO_address@gmail.com>

But on Display FROM name (Alias is not reflecting)